# Sort by partial value of column - Unix

Tags: unix, sorting, partial

I have some fields in the following format

```
apple   banana   blue   xyz=4;pqr=5;mno=3
lemon   banana   red    xyz=2;pqr=6;mno=7
horse   tiger    green  xyz=3;pqr=2;mno=1
```

I want to sort them by the "pqr" value of the 4th column so that my output is :

```
horse   tiger    green  xyz=3;pqr=2;mno=1
apple   banana   blue   xyz=4;pqr=5;mno=3
lemon   banana   red    xyz=2;pqr=6;mno=7
```

I tried the following :

cat file.txt | sort -key=4.2 , however that does not work since it takes the 2nd character for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try splitting your semicolumn separated fields in tab separated fields

```
cat file1 | sed 's/;/;\t/g'

apple   banana   blue   xyz=4;  pqr=5;  mno=3
lemon   banana   red    xyz=2;  pqr=6;  mno=7
horse   tiger    green  xyz=3;  pqr=2;  mno=1
```

...sorting your output and then merging back your fields

```
cat file1 | sed 's/;/;\t/g' | sort --key=5 | sed 's/;\t/;/g'

horse   tiger    green  xyz=3;pqr=2;mno=1
apple   banana   blue   xyz=4;pqr=5;mno=3
lemon   banana   red    xyz=2;pqr=6;mno=7
```

Not the best solution but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. It ignores blanks and non-printing characters, uses `;` to divide the fields, and sorts on the second field.

```
sort -bi -t\; -k2 file.txt
```